# Не сортируется набор массивов по массиву r_razn

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

x-координата x, y-координата y , r-набор колличества красного, g-набор колличества зелёного, b-набор колличества синего, rrazn- разница межде следующим и предыдущим значениями по модулю переменной r , grazn-разница межде следующим и предыдущим значениями по модулю переменной g, brazn-разница межде следующим и предыдущим значениями по модулю переменной b.
**Код:**

```
import csv
import csv
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image  # Подключим необходимые библиотеки.
image = Image.open("E:\Belka2\S939-3-5-5.jpg") #Открываем изображение.
width, height = image.size
print('The original image size is {wide} wide x {height} '
          'high'.format(wide=width, height=height))
size = (1200, 1200)
resized_image = image.resize(size)
width, height = resized_image.size
print('The resized image size is {wide} wide x {height} ' 'high'.format(wide=width, height=height))
resized_image.show()
resized_image.save("S939.jpg")



pix = resized_image.load() #Выгружаем значения пикселей.e


with open('S939-3-5-5-main-diagonal-comby-max-1200-1200.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
   headers = ['x', 'y', 'r', 'g', 'b', 'r_razn', 'g_razn', 'b_razn']
   writer.writerow(headers)

   for x in range(1, height):
      for y in range(1, width):
        if(x == y):
         r, g, b = pix[x, y]
         rrazn, grazn, brazn = abs(abs(np.array(pix[x, y])-np.array(pix[x-1, y-1])))

        
         results = [x, y, r, g, b, rrazn.sort(), grazn, brazn]
         writer.writerow(results)
```

Собираюсь вывести сортированные по **rrazn**  данные в csv файл. Подскажите, как это сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]